# How do you stack area plots with multiple vectors?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am getting data out of a model in a wide format, a row for each week in a time period and a column for each output.  Example fabricated data below.

```
month <- as.Date(c('2010-10-1','2010-11-1','2010-12-1'))
John_Doe <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
Peter_Gynn <- c(14500, 14800, 35300)
Jolie_Hope <- c(49200, 28600, 26800)
employ.data1 <- data.frame(month, John_Doe, Peter_Gynn, Jolie_Hope)
```

Trying to do a stacked plot of each vector but not working, they just overlap each other.

```
ggplot(employ.data1) + geom_area(aes(x=month, y=John_Doe), position='stack') + geom_area(aes(x=month, y=Peter_Gynn), position='stack') + geom_area(aes(x=month, y=Jolie_Hope), position='stack')
```

I understand that if my data was laid out long format I could do this pretty easily. See below, but this is not the way my data is.  Would consider a simple solution to fix the above, or to transfer the data to the format below.

```
employee <- c('John Doe','John Doe','John Doe','Peter Gynn','Peter Gynn','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope','Jolie Hope','Jolie Hope')
month <- as.Date(c('2010-10-1','2010-11-1','2010-12-1','2010-10-1','2010-11-1','2010-12-1','2010-10-1','2010-11-1','2010-12-1'))
expense <- c(21000, 23400, 26800, 14500, 14800, 35300, 49200, 28600, 26800)
employ.data2 <- data.frame(employee, month, expense)

ggplot(employ.data2) + geom_area(aes(x=month, y=expense, fill=employee), position='stack')
```

In the example I have shown three columns, in reality there may be any number coming out of the model, so planning to use a "for in" loop to update the chart with each additional vector.

Thanks for the response, additionally:

It puts the areas in alphabetical order, I can't work out how to order them the way I want them ordered, with Peter in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to gather the data into long format using `tidyr`:

```
library("tidyr")
employ_tidy <- gather(employ.data1, employee, expense, -month)
employ_tidy
##        month   employee expense
## 1 2010-10-01   John_Doe   21000
## 2 2010-11-01   John_Doe   23400
## 3 2010-12-01   John_Doe   26800
## 4 2010-10-01 Peter_Gynn   14500
## 5 2010-11-01 Peter_Gynn   14800
## 6 2010-12-01 Peter_Gynn   35300
## 7 2010-10-01 Jolie_Hope   49200
## 8 2010-11-01 Jolie_Hope   28600
## 9 2010-12-01 Jolie_Hope   26800
```

Comment: And this will work for any additional number of employees.

Comment: Thanks for this, that worked really well, one more question, how do you get them in the order you need them, rather than in alphbetical order?  I have resorted to renameing them aaa_John_Doe, bbb_Peter_Gynn, ccc_Julie_Hope.  This seems like a bit of a poor way to do it.